# Why assume no degeneracy in Spin operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, hamiltonian

The Stern-Gerlach experiment measures a physical property of a quantum system. We hence associate an operator $\hat{S_z}$ with the observable, in accodance with the postulates of QM.

[image]

The eigenvalues of the said operator are all the possible values yielded by the SG apparatus; Hence $\pm\hbar/2$.

I was wondering why we assume those eigenvalues are non-degenerate i.e. have only one eigenvector each? When in an experiment, do we need degenerate eigenvalues for the operator?